# How to get those links by file_get_contents which appears after the page has loaded

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I was working on the code to get the links from a web page of a site

I had used simple_html_dom bu no use as i could not get the links from the website which appears when the web page is loaded on the browser

I also tried to use curl and file_get_content still no luck

can any one help plz

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're talking about bits of the page that were loaded (by ajax calls) after the page completed, and thus are not part of the raw HTML?

Comment: No i am taking about the sub links that appear after the page has loaded that can be because of ajax or php

Comment: So, we're talking about the same. Since `file_get_contents()` only loads the raw HTML of a page, and doesn't execute any javascript, to do ajax calls, you're not getting the links, and therefore cannot find them. Look in the HTML code and see if you can immitate the ajax call. You will have to give the URL if you want any further help.